# Python: Send incoming serial data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, serial-port

I am trying to write a simple **python** script that will read incoming serial data (usb adaptor) at 115200. After each line is received it must upload it to MySQL running in a Synology NAS in the same network.

The problem I see with the **mysql INSERT** from within python is that it can take from 0,5 seconds to 1,3 seconds and during this time any incoming messages would be lost, probably several ones.

I have tried many **threading** options codes but cant get it to work as normally example codes show you how to run 1, 2 or 3 threads at the same time, but what I need is to create threads as they are required by the incoming data.

btw: Using Raspberry Pi.

As a reference, some of the examples I have tried:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Rather than mucking about with threading, you should investigate why your INSERT is taking so long.

Comment: how long should it take? And even if it takes 0,1 seconds I would not be reading the Serial port during this time. Anyway my code is pretty simple to test: import MySQLdb
import time

start = time.time()

db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.1.xxx","","","" )

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = """INSERT INTO test (v1, v2) VALUES (111, 222)"""

try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

db.close()

print "time: " + str(time.time() - start)                             Suggestions of a better approach?

Comment: I have added some middle timing and quite interesting to see that 99% of the time wasted is in the mysqldb.connect. As you can see from these data below. Would it be a good idea to hold the db connect open always?   --------- time after connect: 1.02 wrt previous: 1.02
--------- time after cursor: 1.02 wrt previous: 0.0
--------- time after execute: 1.09 wrt previous: 0.07
--------- time after close: 1.1 wrt previous: 0.0

Comment: I have modified the code to keep the database connection opened and made a infinite loop to INSERT a query every 20 seconds. The time to execute the query is reporting to be from 0,05 to 0,07seconds including console print. This is much better than the 1.3seconds of before. I will implement this change in the original script which receives the serial data and test if its fast enought so I dont need threading. I will report back. Anyway, as a learning exercise I still would like to know if threading could be possible, anyone? thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about just two threads - the first monitoring the serial data & creating a list of messages to be stored - the second to monitor the list of messages, if not empty then store to the database & remove from the list.

Comment: sounds good Paul, I did try something similar but my coding was not up to the job as I couldnt make it work. Any help you can provide for me to start of? Thanks

Comment: I would use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for storing the list but can't be of much more help with Python - only just started looking at it myself.

Comment: Thanks anyway Paul, maybe someone else can build from it and help me out. I am going to do some tests myself, if I manage to get it I will post it but any further help is really appreciated.